# Итерация счётчика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как при клике на блок plus+i увеличивать значение счётчика на 1 или уменьшать при нажатии на блок minus+i, у меня не срабатывает обработка клика по блоку minus и plus?

```js
<script>
  var i = 0;
  </script>
  <script>
      $(".buyprod").click(function () {
        var img = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
        if($('.item'+i).length) {
          document.getElementById('input'+i).value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input'+i).value,10)+1;
        }
        else{
          $("#cartdiv").append('<div id="cart_item" class="item'+i+'"><div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item"><img src="'+ img +'" alt="photo1"><br><div class="plus'+i+'" onclick="i='+i+'">-</div><input id="input'+i+'" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="5" step="1"><div class="minus'+i+'"><button onclick="i='+i+'">+</button></div></div></div></div>');
          alert(i);
          }
      });
      $(".minus"+i).click(function () {
        document.getElementById('input'+i).value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input'+i).value,10)-1;
      });
      $(".plus"+i).click(function () {
        document.getElementById('input'+i).value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input'+i).value,10)+1;
      });
  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position:fixed;top:10px;right:10px;z-index:100000">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyprod" style="background:url(https://romansaburov.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/shoping-cart-min.jpg);background-size:cover;width:60px;height:60px;border-radius:40px;"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center" style="background:black;color:white;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 tovitem">
        <h2>Товар 1</h2>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/29/16/31/numbers-1487222_960_720.png" alt="tovar" class="img-fluid" style="float:right;">
        <p>Описание товара</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info buyprod" type="button" name="button" onclick="i=1">Buy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 tovitem">
        <h2>Товар 2</h2>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/29/16/31/numbers-1487225_960_720.png" alt="tovar" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Описание товара</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info buyprod" type="button" name="button" onclick="i=2">Buy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 tovitem">
        <h2>Товар 3</h2>
        <img src="http://test1.nikkei.edu.hk/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/3.png" alt="tovar" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Описание товара</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info buyprod" type="button" name="button" onclick="i=3">Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade right" id="buyprod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">

  <!-- Add class .modal-side and then add class .modal-top-right (or other classes from list above) to set a position to the modal -->
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-side modal-top-right" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="cartdiv">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В чем заключается Ваш вопрос? Похоже, что его нет, т.к даже вопросительного знака в Вашем тексте нет.

Comment: @IgorR. у меня не срабатывает обработка клика по блокам plus и minus

Comment: рабочий пример хотя бы реализуйте, чтобы можно было покликать

Comment: @WVFFLIFE откройте на весь экран там можно будет добавить товар, ссылки на бутстрап с оф. сайта взял, всё равно ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      ...
      $("#cartdiv").append('<div id="cart_item" ...<div class="minus" data-index="'+i+'">...');
      ...

  $(document).on("click", ".minus", function () {
    var index = +$(this).data("index");
    document.getElementById('input' + index).value =
      parseInt(document.getElementById('input' + index).value, 10) - 1;
  });
```

```js
var i = 1;
$("#cartdiv").append(`
<div class="cart_item">
  <div class="minus" data-index=${i}>minus</div>
  <input type="test" id="input${i}" value="0"/>
<div class="plus" data-index=${i}>plus</div>
</div>
`);
i = 2;
$("#cartdiv").append(`
<div class="cart_item">
  <div class="minus" data-index=${i}>minus</div>
  <input type="test" id="input${i}" value="0"/>
<div class="plus" data-index=${i}>plus</div>
</div>
`);

$(document).on("click", ".minus", function() {
  var index = +$(this).data("index");
  document.getElementById('input' + index).value =
    parseInt(document.getElementById('input' + index).value, 10) - 1;
});
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function() {
  var index = +$(this).data("index");
  document.getElementById('input' + index).value =
    parseInt(document.getElementById('input' + index).value, 10) + 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Не сработало, может что-то ещё не так?

Comment: @Alexander `$(document).on("click", ".minus", function () {`

Comment: попробовал и так, не работает, посмотрите здесь, пожалуйста https://codepen.io/bond1013/pen/zYYNQGR